# c++ Object in different place and keeping alive

Tags: c++, class, object, oop, pointers

I'm new to c++ and I'm trying to understand the OOP side of the language and the pointers with (especially smart pointers) in a case for a web caching.

Imagine that I have two classes like this:

```
template<typename k, typename v>
class A{
 private:
  std::list<std::pair<k, v>> objectList;
  int capacity;
 public:
  void put(k,v); //this function is used to add the values in the objectList
};
```

```
class B{
 private:
  string value;
  string text;
 public:
  void setValue();
  string getResult();
};
```

It is assumed that the implementation of class A and B is written.

My question:

In my source file file of class B, I want to create an instance of my class A in the setValue() function which can be used either everywhere in my function or everywhere in the class but the most important that it is not destroyed with each transaction.

How I could do to create an object A in B, keep it alive and use it in the functions I want from my class B. **Using reference or pointer (smart pointer) i think too....**

I hope I have succeeded in explaining my problem, thank you for reading.

I tried several things:

1st: I added in my header of class B a variable

```
A<std::string, std::string>& _v
```

Then I call it in the source file of class A to call the put() function to add the data I want to it.

2e:

I also tried this:

```
A<std::string, std::string> _a(capacity);
```

My concern is that I create a new object each time my method is called, and it is destroyed afterwards.

info: by wandering on several forums and tutorials / courses, I understood that it is necessary to avoid using new

Comment: You can add a member to class `B`, from type `A` (similarly to what you have with `string text`, you need something like: `A myA`. Then this instance will live as long as the `B` object lives.

Comment: The description is not detailed enough. It would be easier if you showed a code snippet with your use case. If there is supposed to be one `A` for each `B` and the `A` is supposed to live as long as the `B`, then `B` should have a `A` non-static member. If there is supposed to be one `A` shared by all `B` for the duration of the program, then `B` should have a `A` static member or a static member function with a static local `A` variable returned by reference.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have two possible solutions.
One is to make the an A ember variable in B. This will give you access to this variable in any member function of B.

This code illustrated the case.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <list>

template<typename tk, typename tv>
class A{
private:
    std::list<std::pair<tk, tv>> objectList;
    int capacity = 0;
public:
    void put(tk k, tv v)
    {
        objectList.push_back(std::pair<tk, tv>(k, v));
        capacity++;
    }; //this function is used to add the values in the objectList
    void print()
    {
        for (auto a: objectList)
        {
            std::cout << a.first << " " << a.second << std::endl;
        }
    };
};
class B{
private:
    std::string value;
    std::string text;
    A<int, int> m_a;
public:
    void setValue(int a, int b)
    {
        m_a.put(a, b);
        m_a.print();
    };
    std::string getResult()
    {
        return std::string();
    };
};

int main()
{
    B _b;

    _b.setValue(1,1);
    _b.setValue(2,2);
    _b.setValue(3,3);
    return 0;
}
```

The second is to make A a static variable in the B member function you want to use it. This will not allow you to access A variable from any other member function of B.

This code illustrated the case.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <list>

template<typename tk, typename tv>
class A{
private:
    std::list<std::pair<tk, tv>> objectList;
    int capacity = 0;
public:
    void put(tk k, tv v)
    {
        objectList.push_back(std::pair<tk, tv>(k, v));
        capacity++;
    }; //this function is used to add the values in the objectList
    void print()
    {
        for (auto a: objectList)
        {
            std::cout << a.first << " " << a.second << std::endl;
        }
    };
};
class B{
private:
    std::string value;
    std::string text;

public:
    void setValue(int a, int b)
    {
        static  A<int, int> _a;
        _a.put(a, b);
        _a.print();
    };
    std::string getResult()
    {
        return std::string();
    };
};

int main()
{
    B _b;

    _b.setValue(1,1);
    _b.setValue(2,2);
    _b.setValue(3,3);
    return 0;
}
```

You can easily make m_a a pointer if need.

Edit as per what I think the questions in the comment section was asking for:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <memory>

template<typename tk, typename tv>
class A{
private:
    std::list<std::pair<tk, tv>> objectList;
    int capacity = 0;
public:
    A(){};
    void put(tk& k, tv& v)
    {
        objectList.push_back(std::pair<tk, tv>(k, v)); // this will copy k and v values.
        capacity++;
    }; //this function is used to add the values in the objectList
    void print()
    {
        for (auto a: objectList)
        {
            std::cout << a.first << " " << a.second << std::endl;
        }
    };
};
class B{
private:
    std::string value;
    std::string text;
    std::shared_ptr<A<int, int>> m_a;
public:
    B( std::shared_ptr<A<int, int>> _a)
    {
        m_a = _a;
    };
    void DoSomethingWithA()
    {
        int k =1, v =1;
        m_a->put(k,v);
        k = 2;
        v = 2;
        m_a->put(k,v);
        k = 3;
        v = 3;
        m_a->put(k,v);
    };
};

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<A<int, int>> _a = std::make_shared<A<int, int>>();
    std::unique_ptr<B> _b = std::make_unique<B>(_a);
    
    _b->DoSomethingWithA();
    
    _a->print();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I have a question, if I pass my class A in the constructor of my class B, this will allow me to create an object of A at the creation of B, and to keep it alive throughout the process of B?

2nd question:

In order not to copy values, I should modify my function to pass references as parameters, like that:

void setValue(int& a, int& b)

Why this question, because no matter where I use m_a, the syntax will always be m_a, no "*" or "&" in solution 1 ?
 
Because i remember when your declare a pointer is mean you have to give reference has value non ?

Comment: 1st: To create A in the constructor of B you do not need to pass it to B. You can just create it in the constructor of B. I am guessing you are wanting to pass it because you want to created outside B and then have B be able to access this with in the class.
2nd: So if you pass by reference the a and b  on that function it means that in that function the variables are the same memory as from where the function was called. Nonetheless, when you push this to the list they will be copied because it is not a list of pointers.  I have edited the answer with what I think covers your question.